# Table of contents with links to scanned pages

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, bookmarks

I have scanned documents (PDF) that are each several hundred pages long. I would like to create a table of contents for each one that has links and bookmarks to section titles.

I have found two partial solutions so far:

1. Use pdfpages with `pdflatex` (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147735/one-page-table-of-contents-with-hyperlinks-for-use-with-pdftk)) to split and merge the scanned file around the table of contents. This works amazingly well, except that a large number of the scanned files have pages that are rotated or double width, and pdfpages shrinks them and places them onto letter sized sheets. Unfortunately, this is unacceptable.
2. Use `latex` with `dvips` and Ghostscript to create a merged PDF. This creates bookmarks, but not links to the sections. This is a slight improvement over option #1.

The ideal solution would be to use LaTeX only. Is this possible without changing the dimensions of the scanned PDFs?

Here is a sample of my code:

```latex
% DO NOT EDIT. All changes to this file will be overwritten by mktoc-latex.
\pdfminorversion=6
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.5in, 9in}, left=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=,
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  pdftitle={Manual},
  pdfcreator={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfsubject={Manual},
  unicode=true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\date{}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Table of Contents}\vspace \bigskipamount \par }

  \bookmark[page=1,level=1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
  \contentsline {chapter}{\hyperlink{page.1}{Random Bookmark}}{1}{}
  \bookmark[page=1,level=1]{Random Bookmark}
  % The target is in the document that is included using pdfpages. If the document is not 
  % appended to the TOC, pdflatex will complain and fix the links when creating the PDF, 
  % but latex seems to keep the links and bookmarks when creating the DVI.
  \contentsline {chapter}{\hyperlink{page.101}{Random Bookmark 2}}{101}{}
  \bookmark[page=101,level=1]{Random Bookmark 2}

\includepdf[pages={1-},frame=false]{scanned.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539337/2388

Comment: @Mensch Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.